# How can I value a form without a name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a form and I need to value the inputa in the form here. I can get the value of this input with the following code. But when I want to value, I cannot. Since I am new to Js, I did not understand what the problem was. But I think it's about array. If you could help me, I would appreciate it.

[click for html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpcUd.png)

i can get input value with this code line;

```
var getInputBuyValue = document.getElementsByClassName('create-order exchange-card layout-l')[0].getElementsByClassName('limit-market-buy')[0];
console.log(getInputBuyValue[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cssSelector = '.create-order.exchange-card.layout-l .limit-market-buy .input-coin-box input[type="text"]'
var input = document.querySelector(cssSelector)
input.value = 'new value'
```